# Lazy load feature modules, ngrx action trigged before reducer is initialize

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm facing following problem. My action is fired before my reducer is initialised. For this reason my reducer don't pick up the action. How can I affect it that my reducer picks up actions when fired before my reducer has been initialised?

This image shows you the redux flow.

[image]

My action is dispatched from a ConfigurationEffect. And should be captured by different XFeature-reducers these reducers are feature based reducers

Code example:

app module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('config', fromConfig.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ConfigEffects]),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }), 
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 10,
      name: 'Debug DevTools',
      logOnly: true,
      actionSanitizer,
      stateSanitizer,
    }), 
  ], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

config effects

```
@Effect()
  loadConfigs$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(configActions.ConfigActionTypes.LoadConfigs),
    switchMap((action: configActions.LoadConfigs) =>
      this.configService.loadConfig().pipe(
        map((result: ConfigResponse) => new configActions.SaveConfigs(result)),
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => of(new configActions.FailConfigs(err.message))),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

xFeature reducer

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: XFeatureActions | ConfigActions): XFeatureState {
  switch (action.type) {
    // save configs, this will be called when the device is initially loaded.
    case ConfigActionTypes.SaveConfigs:
 ...
})
```

Comment: you should provide a bit more details. most important, where is your action being dispatched from?

Comment: Improved with code example

Comment: hm...that doesn't look like the whole picture. So, usual setup with lazy loaded store is: you have `AppModule` in which you register main reducers&effects using `.forRoot(...)`. Then, you have your lazy loaded angular module, e.g. `MyLazyModule` in which you register your lazy loaded ngrx reducers/effects the same way you do in your `AppModule` with the difference that now you use `.forFeature(...)` instead of `.forRoot(...)`. In short, remove `.forFeature(...)` registrations from your `AppModule` and put them into your lazy loaded module.

Comment: But then my other reducers are still loaded after the action has been send. The only way to affect a solution for now is to load all reducers on startup time, which I want to avoid. There should be like a replay action or something else

Comment: which other reducers? i am sorry, i might be missing something, but i have hard time understanding your overall app structure. in particular, which angular modules you have and which corresponding ngrx  module you have and then what actions (from which ngrx module) are fired where and cause problems. It would be beneficial if you could clarify that a bit.

Comment: Your expecting lazy-loaded reducers (which by definition will not be loaded until accessed) to act on an action, I’m still quite new to NGRX but this sounds wrong, better approach is your root store handles the action and stores the config in the root state, your feature modules would then use a selector to access this data

Comment: @BoVandersteene did you manage to find the solution to this (if you remember)? I am seeing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

i had these lines.
this action performs before the lazy loaded module get loaded even if swap these lines out.

```
this.store.dispatch(new Action());
this.router.navigate(['/lazy']);
```

but a bit later i got that it should work this way to wait lazy module loading (this means registering all feature things like reducers, effects...) to perform the action.

```
this.router.navigate(['/lazy'])
    .then(_ => {
        this.store.dispatch(new Action());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain if this is what you're looking for but when a reducer is registered, NgRx dispatches a `update-reducers` action. You can listen to these actions inside your effect in order to disaptch the `SaveConfig` action.

Pre NgRx 7 this looks as:

```
{type: '@ngrx/store/update-reducers', feature: 'feature1'}
{type: '@ngrx/store/update-reducers', feature: 'feature2'}
```

Starting from NgRx 7 this looks as:

```
{type: '@ngrx/store/update-reducers', features: ['feature1',
'feature2']}
```

Comment: yes, everytime the structure of the top level reducers change